# Record a room with people without miking them individually

Tags: microphone, omni, conference

Hey I need to record a room of up to 20 people.

(Its a so called hybrid seminar in which some people are participating via zoom and some are physically attending it).
The goal is that the people in the room are audible to the people in the zoom call.

So far one omnidirectional mike produced mediocre/bad results. One thing that I thought about was using 2-4 omnidriectional mikes instead, however my budget is only about 200€ so Im not sure wether thats even an option. Would it be better to buy a single but good microphone?

The room is about 6x12 metres big.

Answer (score 1):

Your only solution within budget is to have hand-held mic(s), passed to each speaker in turn. Optimally each mic has a handler to do the physical moves. (You could squeeze that into budget by bringing in a couple of junior employees rather than specialists.)

Your ideal solution would be to have two boom operators. Each of these guys would charge you your total budget… per day.

Hanging omnis in a space that size wouldn't be a practical solution. You'd still be fighting falloff, or over-compressing & raising background noise - unless your participants can be relied upon to remain *absolutely* silent whilst not speaking (not going to happen).

btw, in 2020 I don't know how you would achieve this & maintain social distancing rules. It's not a meeting you could get me to go to, unless every participant had a proven negative covid test within the past 24 hours.

Comment: I am sensing some sarcasm in your comment^^
The research Ive done pretty much confirms what you are saying, the social distancing is part of the problem since people have to be relatively spreaded out.

Comment: No sarcasm - some cynicism perhaps;) I work in the film industry - you ought to see the hoops we all have to jump through to keep the industry open. Everybody covid tests  (every single production day) either the day before & self-isolates or on the day & has to go sit back in their car until they get the all-clear. Everyone is held separately in 3m sq booths off set, then in social bubbles on set, masks on until right before each take. 20 people in  a room that size wouldn't be allowed, even with all clean tests. We've **still** had some productions shut down because of positive tests.